# Why use alias to resolving fan trap?

Tags: sql, database, business-objects

I just have been confused with SAP universe and fan trap.

Why use alias to resolve the fan trap?

Does it generate useless and redundancy SQL?

What is the SQL difference after used alias?

Comment: try post some code and your specific doubts

Comment: reference link:https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/sap-bo-tutorial-252/resolving-fan-traps-4316.html

Comment: If it's the only way to resolve the issue (which it is) then there is nothing redundant in your code

Comment: If you want the correct results in your reports then you need to understand the concept of "fan trap". The reference given above it pretty clear I think. If you are providing aggregations but also joining to data in a one-to-many, and again in a one-to-many manner, then the number of rows gets multiplied, and this also multiples the aggregated results (i.e. wrong outcomes).  The stated solution method **requires** use of aliases, so the aliases have a purpose and cannot therefore be redundant.